# Calculator that logs the calculations for print on request

Tags: logging, calculator

I don't know if my title is very explanatory. I'm new to java (1 week in). If I use some words or expressions wrong, forgive me. xD

I've just made my own calculator. I did this pretty much without any help from other sources. Nice to start to remember the Java syntax by my own. :D

**This is the code for the Calculator I made:**

```
// Calc with the switch statement.
```

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calcswitch {
    public static void main(String[] args )  {

```
    // Different variables

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    double fnum = 0;
    double snum = 0;
    double answer = 0;
    int whatOperation;

    String finalquestion = "";
    boolean calculateAgain = true; // Goes inside the while loop


    while (calculateAgain) {
    // Ask what type of calculation you want to perform.
    System.out.println("\n");
    System.out.println("Press 1 for +");
    System.out.println("Press 2 for -");
    System.out.println("Press 3 for *");
    System.out.println("Press 4 for /");

    whatOperation = input.nextInt();


    switch (whatOperation) {

    case 1:
        // Addition
        System.out.print("Enter first number:  ");
        fnum = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter second number:  ");
        snum = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("The result is:  ");
        System.out.print(fnum + snum);
        break;

    case 2:
        // Subtraction
        System.out.print("Enter first number:  ");
        fnum = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter second number:  ");
        snum = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("The result is:  ");
        System.out.print(fnum - snum);
        break;

    case 3:
        // Multiplication
        System.out.print("Enter first number:  ");
        fnum = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter second number:  ");
        snum = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("The result is:  ");
        System.out.print(fnum * snum);
        break;

    case 4:
        // Division
        System.out.print("Enter first number:  ");
        fnum = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter second number:  ");
        snum = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("The result is:  ");
        System.out.print(fnum / snum);  
        break;

        default: 
            System.out.print("You have entered an invalid number. ");
            break;

        }

    // Asks if you want to use the Calculator again
    System.out.print("\n\nDo you want to use the calculator again? Yes / No:   ");
    finalquestion = input.next();

    // If no, the string calculateAgain goes false, and exit the while loop.
    if (finalquestion.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {


        calculateAgain = false;


    }


    }

    // After the while loop. 
    System.out.println("Thank you for using this calculator");
}
```

}

Now I want to implement a neat little feature that logs the answers. If the user want to see his calculations since he started using the program, he will be able to do this by writing "log" or something similar.

The problem is. I'm not sure how I can log the answers. One way to do it is by making a lot of strings and keep them empty. However, this would not be very dynamic I guess. And what would happens if I have 10 declared strings for logging, but the user have done 15 calculations? It would not work good.

Does java have a method for logging user input, and store them in a dynamic way that is easy to recall later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about one big string , add a new line for every log

```
String LOG = "LOG INFO";

// WHEN YOU WANT TO ADD A LOGENTRY TO YOUR LOG
String NewLogEntry = "REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_LOG_INFO";
LOG = LOG + /n + NewLogEntry;
```

Comment: Genius! Did not thing about it in that way. This is just like I did my counter yesterday. Double total = total + newsum

Comment: Thanks, I'm glad I could help.